# Parsing an XML in Java using STax

Tags: java, xml, parsing, stax

This, even to me, seems like a silly question but then is one of those to which i cant find an answer.

Im trying to parse an XML using STax in Java and the XMl im trying to parse looks like this --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Macros>
    <MacroDefinition>
            <MacroName>
                <string>Macro1</string>
            </MacroName>
    </MacroDefinition>
</Macros>
```

Now i have a Macro class as follows --

```
 public class Macro {
    private String name; 

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    }
```

I also have a parser class from where i try to convert the XML into an object of the 'Macro' class. The parser class snippet is as follows --

```
public class StaxParser {
    static final String MACRODEFINITION = "MacroDefinition";
    static final String MACRONAME = "MacroName";
    static final String STRING = "string";

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "null" })
    public List<Item> readMacro(String configFile) {
        List<Macro> macroList = new ArrayList<Macro>();
        try {
            // First create a new XMLInputFactory
            XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            // Setup a new eventReader
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(configFile);
            XMLEventReader eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(in);
            // Read the XML document
            Macro macro = null;

            while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
                XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();

                if (event.isStartElement()) {
                    StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
                    if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart() == (MACRODEFINITION)) {
                        macro = new Macro();

                    }

                    if (event.isStartElement()) {
                        if (event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart()
                                .equals(MACRONAME)) {
                            Iterator<Attribute> attributes = event
                                    .asStartElement().getAttributes();
                            while (attributes.hasNext()) {
                                Attribute attribute = attributes.next();
                                if (attribute.getName().toString()
                                        .equals(STRING)) {
                                    macro.setMacroName(event.asCharacters()
                                            .getData());
                                }
                            }
                            event = eventReader.nextEvent();
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // If we reach the end of an item element we add it to the list
                if (event.isEndElement()) {
                    EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();
                    if (endElement.getName().getLocalPart() == (MACRODEFINITION)) {
                        macroList.add(macro);
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return macroList;
    }

}
```

The problem im facing is that the parser is not able to read the child nodes of 'MacroName'. Im thinking `getAttributes` is what is causing it not to work but have no clue of what method i should be calling to get the child nodes of any particular node.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
p1nG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that  Macro1 is not XML attribute, so event attributes will be empty. Code after changes (*I have only shown lines of code that may be of interest*):

```
  if (event.isStartElement()
     && event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart().equals(STRING)) {
          if (macro == null) {
               macro = new Macro();
          }
           macro.setName(eventReader.getElementText());
  }
```

A few tips: never ever compare strings using == use equals method. If you need full working example I could post my solution, but it is bit more complicated.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to say that, but your code has many issues and doesn't even compile.

First of all, the return type should be `List<Macro>`, since the `Macro` class doesn't inherit from, nor implement, the `Item`.

Second, you should ensure a safe nesting, to follow the schema of your XML, not arbitrarily test for event name equality and create `Macro` objects here and there along the way. If you plan to retreive also other data besides the macro name, you can't get away with just checking for the `STRING` event occurence.

Third, it's useless to nest the same checks, e.g. `event.isStartElement()`.

Fourth, you should provide a `Source` or a `Reader` or a `Stream` to a class such as the StaxParser, not directly a filename, but I didn't include this change to avoid breaking your API.

```
class StaxParser {
    static final String MACRODEFINITION = "MacroDefinition";
    static final String MACRONAME = "MacroName";
    static final String STRING = "string";

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "null" })
    public List<Macro> readMacro(final String configFile) {
        final List<Macro> macroList = new ArrayList<Macro>();
        try {
            // First create a new XMLInputFactory
            final XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            // Setup a new eventReader
            final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(configFile);
            final XMLEventReader eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(in);
            // Read the XML document

            final Template template = getTemplate(eventReader);
            macroList.addAll(template.process(null, getMacrosProcessor(template)));

        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final XMLStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return macroList;
    }

    interface Template {
        <T> T process(String parent, EventProcessor<T> ep) throws XMLStreamException;
    }

    static Template getTemplate(final XMLEventReader eventReader) {
        return new Template() {
            @Override
            public <T> T process(final String parent, final EventProcessor<T> ep) throws XMLStreamException {
                T t = null;
                boolean process = true;
                while (process && eventReader.hasNext()) {
                    final XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
                    if (ep.acceptsEvent(event)) {
                        t = ep.processEvent(event);
                    }
                    if (event.isEndElement()) {
                        if (null != parent && parent.equals(event.asEndElement().getName().getLocalPart())) {
                            process = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return t;
            }
        };
    }

    interface EventProcessor<T> {
        boolean acceptsEvent(XMLEvent event);

        T processEvent(XMLEvent event) throws XMLStreamException;
    }

    static EventProcessor<List<Macro>> getMacrosProcessor(final Template template) {
        final List<Macro> macroList = new ArrayList<Macro>();
        return new EventProcessor<List<Macro>>() {
            @Override
            public boolean acceptsEvent(final XMLEvent event) {
                return event.isStartElement()
                        && MACRODEFINITION.equals(event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart());
            }

            @Override
            public List<Macro> processEvent(final XMLEvent event) throws XMLStreamException {
                macroList.add(template.process(MACRODEFINITION, getMacroDefinitionProcessor(template)));
                return macroList;
            }
        };
    }

    static EventProcessor<Macro> getMacroDefinitionProcessor(final Template template) {
        return new EventProcessor<Macro>() {
            @Override
            public boolean acceptsEvent(final XMLEvent event) {
                return event.isStartElement() && MACRONAME.equals(event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart());
            }

            @Override
            public Macro processEvent(final XMLEvent event) throws XMLStreamException {
                final Macro macro = new Macro();
                macro.setName(template.process(MACRONAME, getMacroNameProcessor(template)));
                return macro;
            }
        };
    }

    static EventProcessor<String> getMacroNameProcessor(final Template template) {
        return new EventProcessor<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean acceptsEvent(final XMLEvent event) {
                return event.isStartElement() && STRING.equals(event.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart());
            }

            @Override
            public String processEvent(final XMLEvent event) throws XMLStreamException {
                return template.process(STRING, getStringProcessor());
            }
        };
    }

    static EventProcessor<String> getStringProcessor() {
        return new EventProcessor<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean acceptsEvent(final XMLEvent event) {
                return event.isCharacters();
            }

            @Override
            public String processEvent(final XMLEvent event) throws XMLStreamException {
                return event.asCharacters().getData();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: i must admit. it took me a while to figure out what you're doing in this code snippet, but its by far the best way i've seen so far to parse xml with StAX!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change 
     macro.setMacroName(event.asCharacters().getData());

to
     macro.setMacroName(attribute.getvalue().toString());